# Android setViewValue cannot cast to ImageView

Tags: android, casting

Setting the ViewBinder to alternate the image in the listView:

```
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.contacts_row, c, new String[] {
                            c.getColumnName(1), c.getColumnName(2) },
                    new int[] { R.id.c_title, R.id.c_description });

            adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor c, int columnIndex) {

                    // Variant 1: displayImage = (ImageView) view;
                    // Variant 2: displayImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

                    displayImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.good);

                    // }

                    return true;

                }
            });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Call stack:

- java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast
  to android.widget.ImageView
- E/AndroidRuntime(8693): at
  xxxx.android.Contacts$2.setViewValue(Contacts.java:133)

Please help to clarify why view there is an error in both Variant 1 and 2

Comment: First clean your project and run it again

Comment: `android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
E/AndroidRuntime(8693):` this says you are trying to cast TextView into ImageView at line number 133

Comment: If you are still getting error means, you are trying to convert textView to ImageView.

Comment: Cleaned - no results;
Regenerated R - no results;
Yes, I know it tries to cast it from text to image, because View view - TextView; How to overcome it?

Comment: In this line what is view(TextView or ImageView) setViewValue(View view, Cursor c, int columnIndex)

Comment: @Ivan you can't change the imageView in your binder as it will work with `TextViews`. You can do it somewhere else, depending on your logic. What are the situations when you want to trigger image update ?

Comment: @kiruwka I'm adding images to the 5 rows depending on what value is in c.getColumnName(1)

Comment: That is what we are saying... How can we convert TextView to imageView? In this line Variant 1: displayImage = (ImageView) view; you are trying to convert TextView to ImageView so it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

I think set view value will be call for all view. But you want to set image on image view only. I think you can try this.

```
try {
    displayImage = (ImageView) view;
    displayImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    displayImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.good);
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
}
```

or you can try this also.

```
if (view instanceof ImageView) {
     // DO YOUR IMAGEVIEW RELATED STUFF HERE.
    displayImage = (ImageView) view;
    displayImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    displayImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.good);
}
```

Actual problem is setViewValue will be called for different types of views and you can't type cast all your views in ImageView. In your case, your row layout contains Textview and ImageView both when setViewValue will be called for ImageView then no problem you can typecast and use but when it will be called for any other type of view then it will fire exception as you can't typecast it. Hope it can help you. :)